# Send notification payload to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase to send push notification to a `WebViewController()`.
The notification received has a URL payload, I've successfully got the URL from the payload, but now I couldn't send it to my `WebViewController()` when the user taps on the notification.

Here is the method for the payload method which gets called when the user taps on the notification:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: Any] {
        if let alertPayload = aps["alert"] as? String {
            let webViewController = WebViewController()
            webViewController.urlString = alertPayload
            let url = URL(string: alertPayload)
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
            webViewController.webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
        }
    }

    completionHandler()
}
```

And here is the `WebViewController()`

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }
}
```

Please keep note that I'm successfully receiving the notification but the app crashes when I click on the notification whenever I call this:

webViewController.webView.loadRequest(urlRequest) and saying it `found nil`

Answer (score 1):

The crash occurs because the `webView` have not yet loaded in your `webViewController`. We cannot simply instantiate using `let webViewController = WebViewController()`, espcially if you are using storyboard.

The common way to handle push notification and reload the new content (in your case to reload new url) is using NotificationCenter (assumed you are using Swift 3). The NotificationCenter is like you are adding listener / observer in controller and wait if events occur

First, add observer to your `webViewController` where you want to do changes in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // some of your codes here
    // ...
    // ...

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(WebViewController.reloadWebview(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("NotificationReloadWebView"), object: nil)
}
```

Then add method to handle if the notification happens

```
func reloadWebview(notification: Notification) {
    if let url = notification.userInfo?["url"] as? UIImage {
        // load the url to webview
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        self.webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }
}
```

Lastly, trigger the observer by send Post Notification in `AppDelegate` once you receive new push notification

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: Any] {
        if let newUrl = aps["alert"] as? String {
            let info = ["url": newUrl]

            // post notification with info (url)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationReloadWebView"), object: nil, userInfo: info)
        }
    }

    completionHandler()
}
```